# Python Control Flow (Identifying different POST methods in same app route - Flask)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm in Flask. I have two forms on one html page, both with post methods to the same route. I have read that it is possible to use control flow to identify which form is being posted, under the same app route. I seem to be battling with the logic here. So far I have the below:

```
@app.route('/page-with-2-forms, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def function():

    if request.method == "POST":

        if 'form_1_element_name' in request.form: 
        
            #form1
            #request args from this form and do some stuff
        
        #form2
        else:
            #request args from this form and do some stuff
    
    return render_template('page.html')
```

The problem here is that when attempting to post #form1 it still attempts to execute the block for #form2 (the else statement). However, when posting #form2 everything works fine. As I said I seem to be missing some logic here.

The element name tag is posted under the html  tag. `<form id="form_1_element_name" name="form_1_element_name" action="page-with-2-forms" method="POST">`

Please note that I know the conventional practice is to use WTForms, but I do not want to use it here

Any help would be massively appreciated

Comment: Could you add the value of `request.form`?

Comment: @go2nirvana the `request.form` calls for the form's name, which is in the `<form>` tag as described above. Do you think this may be the issue? Maybe rather put a hidden element in the form's body itself?

Comment: What i'm trying to check is if your conditions actually work. `if` is a solid construction, if it "falses" - that is because condition is False. So maybe there is actually no `'form_1_element_name'` in `request.form`

Comment: @go2nirvana just resolved it, thanks. You were technically right. It doesn't work to reference the name of the form as an element. You need to reference an element within the form, so I referenced the name of the submit button within the form and works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will post the solution just for future reference and people having similar issues. In the original post, the `if statement` references the form name, as stated in the html snippet

```
<form id="form_1_element_name" name="form_1_element_name" action="page-with-2-forms" method="POST">
```

This doesn't work. Instead, the `if statement` should reference an element *inside* the actual form. In the below, I referenced the submit button, which is ID and named to a unique name, such as "editFormSubmitButton".

```
@app.route('/page-with-2-forms, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def function():

    if request.method == "POST":

        if 'editFormSubmitButton' in request.form: 
        
            #form1
            #request args from this form and do some stuff
        
        #form2
        else:
            #request args from this form and do some stuff
    
    return render_template('page.html')
```

This is a great alternative to WTForms

Thanks to @go2nirvana for the bit of help